# asp.net c# validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I am trying to create a simple form that uses radio buttons.  I set the radio button to AutoPostBack = True, this way if the radio button is true/false, a subpanel is Shown or Hidden.  The radio buttons are required fields.  I also have a hidden textbox that the value of the selected radio button is inserted and this textbox is what I validate against (empty or not).

**Problem 1:**

This works until you go to submit and the validation fails.  The validation messages show, then when you click on one of the radio buttons with AutoPostBack = True, all the validation disappear.  I can resolve this by adding Page.Validate() to the method that runs when the radio button is clicked.  But, I do not want the Page.Validate() to run unless the page was already showing validation errors (so it will not re-validate unless the form was already submitted and failed the validation).

As it stands, before the form is submitted and fails validation: when you click on any radio button question, all the other questions requiring validation show the validation error.  I am only looking to overcome the AutoPostBack which is clearing all the validation messages that are shown when you had click submit.

**Problem 2:**

I would like to be able to change the color of the question if it does not pass validation.  I added the javascript to override the default .net settings.  I got this to work, but only when you click the submit button and not after a RadioButton AutoPostBack.

Currently, When you click submit all the required questions turn red and also display the required validation message.  But if you click a radio button to start fixing the validation errors, on the AutoPostBack, the all the questions that were now red in color changes back to the orignal black and the required validation message is still shown.  How can I call the Javascript to run again along with the Page.Validation() in the code behind method?

Any help would be greatly appricated! Thanks

Below is an example of the code so far.

ASPX Code:

```
    <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" CellSpacing="0" CellPadding="0">
<asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableCell CssClass="question">
<label>4. Have you had an abnormal result from a prenatal test (e.g. amniocentesis, blood test, ultrasound)?</label>

</asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell CssClass="answer">
<ul class="selectGroup">
<li>
<asp:RadioButton ID="Q4_true" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Q4_yes") %>' Text="Yes"
GroupName="4" OnCheckedChanged='RB_QuestionSubPane_YN' AutoPostBack="true" /></li>
<li>
<asp:RadioButton ID="Q4_false" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Q4_no") %>' Text="No"
GroupName="4" OnCheckedChanged='RB_QuestionSubPane_YN' AutoPostBack="true" />
</li>
<asp:TextBox ID="Q4_validationBox" runat="server" CssClass="hiddenField" Enabled="false"
Text=''></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" EnableViewState="true" ControlToValidate="Q4_validationBox"
Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</ul>
</asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Code Behind

```
    protected void RB_QuestionSubPane_YN(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

RadioButton radio_Selected = (RadioButton)sender;
string radio_QuestionID = Convert.ToString(radio_Selected.ID);

(((TextBox)FormView1.FindControl(strQuestionID + "_validationBox")).Text) = radio_Selected.ID.ToString();

Page.Validate();

}
```

JavaScript

```
    ValidatorUpdateDisplay = function (val) {
var ctl = $('#' + val.controltovalidate);
var eCount = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
var v = Page_Validators[i];
if (v.controltovalidate == val.controltovalidate) {

if (!v.isvalid) {
eCount++;
ctl.addClass('validationError');
$('td.question:eq(' + i + ')').addClass('red');
}

};
}
if (eCount > 0) {
ctl.addClass('validationError');

} else {
ctl.removeClass('validationError');
$('td.question:eq(' + i + ')').removeClass('red');
}
if (typeof (val.display) == "string") {
if (val.display == "None") {
return;
}
if (val.display == "Dynamic") {
val.style.display = val.isvalid ? "none" : "inline";
return;
}
}
if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac") > -1) &&
(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > -1)) {
val.style.display = "inline";
}
val.style.visibility = val.isvalid ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you really need is custom validation. That way you can fully customize your validation to meet your needs.

Here is a simple example:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
function CustomValidator1_ClientValidate(source,args)
{   
    //put your javascript logic here
}
//-->
</script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>   
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="direction" Text="left" />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="direction" Text="right" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    <asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="please choose" ClientValidationFunction="CustomValidator1_ClientValidate" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Server Side

```
    protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        args.IsValid = RadioButton1.Checked || RadioButton2.Checked;
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            //validate is successful.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have a form that has over 700 questions and I am trying to create a solution so I do not have to write out every radiobutton1.checked for each.

Is there a way to count the number of invalid validations or to check if the validation has ran in the code behind?  This way I could run the Page.Validate() command if the count is greater than 0 or if the validation has run.